# How to bind media keys to Pithos actions?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, kubuntu

I've looked through the settings both of the system and of Pithos, and it seems there is no way to govern Pithos using the media keys (Play/Pause, etc.). I use `pithos` more than `amarok`, so I'd like to bind the media keys to it instead.

I'm using Kubuntu 12.04. Any suggestions?